# How to use titleformatter --- example using CSS classes?

Tags: tabulator

I'd like to render a table as in the screen snippet linked below.

[Mock-up of rendering desired (3 variants, all using the same formatter for columns with sub-headings 'T', 'F')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WUdOF.png)

Thanks to help from Oli Folkerd, I have a version that's working, as in the screen snippet linked below.

[Table as correctly rendered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFpfo.png)

This becomes a non-question, perhaps a useful example.

Header spec:

```
          {title:"T", field:"true", align:"center",
           headerSort:false,
           titleFormatter:title_truthFormatter,
           formatter:childTFormatter}
```

Formatters:

```
function cell_truthFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    var cellElement = cell.getElement();
    if (cellValue == "T") {
    cellElement.style.backgroundColor = "#0000B3"; // Excel: 48, 84, 150 --> #305496
    cellElement.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
    cellElement.style.textAlign = "center";
    cellElement.style.fontWeight = "bold";
    }
    else if (cellValue == "F") {
    cellElement.style.backgroundColor ="#B30000"; // Excel: 192, 0, 0 --> #c00000
    cellElement.style.color = "#FFFFFF";
    cellElement.style.textAlign = "center";
    cellElement.style.fontWeight = 700; // "bold"; // Same...
    }
    else cellElement.style.color = "#000000";
    return cell.getValue();
}

function title_truthFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
    var cellValue = cell.getValue();
    var cellElement = cell.getElement();
    var classToAdd;
    if (cellValue == "T") classToAdd = "truth-true";
    else classToAdd = "truth-false";

    setTimeout(function(){                   
       cell.getElement().parentNode.parentNode.classList.add(classToAdd);
    },100)

    return cell.getValue();
}

function childTFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) { // #8ea9db
    var cellElement = cell.getElement();
    cellElement.style.backgroundColor = "#8ea9db";
    return cell.getValue();
}

function childFFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) { // #ff7578
    var cellElement = cell.getElement();
    cellElement.style.backgroundColor = "#ff7578";
    cellElement.style.fontStyle = "italic";
    return cell.getValue();
}
```

CSS:

```
.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col .truth-true {
    background-color: #0000B3 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center !important;
    padding-top: 8px !important;
    /* No-op, in tabulator header: font-weight: bold; */
}

.tabulator .tabulator-header .tabulator-col .truth-false {
    background-color: #B30000 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center !important;
    padding-top: 8px !important;
    font-style: italic !important;
    /* No-op, in tabulator header: font-weight: bold; */
}
```

Comment: could you include the formatter you are trying to use in this please.

Comment: Added formatter.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, my answer below still stands, you should move it to classes to allow you to better handle the difference in structure of the header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work with your headers there are a few bits we will need to tweak.

You will need to change your css selectors to use the ***.tabulator-col*** class and you will need to and some ***!important*** flags to override the inbuilt styling:

```
.tabulator-col.truth-true {
    background-color: #0000B3 !important;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    text-align: center !important;
}
```

Then in your title formatter you will need to select a couple of nodes up from the element on the cell to get the full header element rather than just the text. also because the parent technically doesn't exist yet, you will need to wait a few miliseconds for it to be added to the DOM

```
function truthFormatter(cell, formatterParams, onRendered) {
    //DO YOUR LOGIC TO DECIDE WHAT CLASS SHOULD BE APPLIED

    setTimeout(function(){                   
       cell.getElement().parentNode.parentNode.classList.add("truth-true");
    },100)

    return cell.getValue();
}
```

At this point it may be simpler to use a separate formatter function for the cells and headers as they need to do different things, though you could also check the classes on the cell element to see if it had the class ***tabulator-cell*** to decice how to then apply the class to the correct element

Comment: I've taken a stab at this but am stuck.  See revised formatter and draft CSS, where I've handled col-title the same as cell, but neither is working.  I'm sure they need different changes.  Can you tell me what?

Comment: do you have a graphic of what it is you want the header to look like?

Comment: I've added a mock-up screen snippet.  Working on the columns sub-headed 'T' and 'F'.

Comment: I've made progress with your latest helpful advice, have updated question to reflect remaining issues.

Comment: Is this use case beyond Tabulator's effective capability?

Comment: Not at all, the above methodology is sound, you just have to use the correct CSS styling in the classes to achieve your desired results. i would suggest you use a CSS inspector in your browser to see where any particular custom styles may be being overridden by tabulators inbuilt styling and either increase the selectors specificity or use an !important flag to force your styling change over the default

Comment: Working now.  I needed to update `title_truthFormatter` to apply `setTimeout` to either CSS class, `add classes .tabulator` and `tabulator-header` to my CSS directives, also add to each directive the CSS attribute `padding-top` with value `8px` (patterned after what I found by inspecting CSS for similarly formatted row data).  All is well---thanks!

Comment: Great stuff, Glad to hear it is all working for you :D

Comment: You shouldn't need any reputation to accept an answer, only to upvote it...

Comment: Done...  Can you offer any feedback on this related question (expanded, since original post)?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53489325/how-to-center-header-horizontal-text-vertically-in-a-tall-cell-in-a-row-includi